# When we say x=10 or list=[], do these literals also call the constructors of int and list internally?

Tags: python

When we say `x=10` or `list=[]`, do these datatype literals also call the constructors of int class (which is `int()`) and of list class (`list()`) internally? Or does it not call the constructor and creates an object without a constructor call? How do literals create an object?

Comment: [] does not call list(), because `["test"] != list("test")`, idk about x = 10.

Comment: @EliHarold that's not a useful comparison, because `list("test")` and `["test"]` do different things anyway. `list("t") == ["t"]`, but `list("test") == ["t", "e", "s", "t"]`.

Comment: I believe that the way objects are created from literals is a matter for the Python implementation to handle. For instance, the standard implementation caches low ints, so the literal `10` would not even create a new int object.

Comment: `[]` is not (technically) a literal, but a *display*. It's not a literal because a display in general is not, well, literal: `x = 3; f = [1,2,x]`. A display is just another kind of expression with special syntax to create a value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was trying to make the point that they are difference, hence my entire comment.

Comment: @EliHarold but that doesn't tell you whether or not `["test"]` calls `list`. An implementation could transform that syntax to `list(("test",))`, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe True, I was commenting on the equality of the two.

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily. The constructors are part of the public API, but the Python runtime is free to handle this however it likes. It may choose to do something more efficient, or something completely different! Consider the following code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(x):
...     return x in [1,2,3]
...
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ((1, 2, 3))
              4 CONTAINS_OP              0
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

The Python runtime doesn't even create a list here at all! It just loads a pre-built *tuple*, since it knows that the `tuple` will suffice here, since the list is never mutated or used for anything else!

But *conceptually*, you can think of it as calling a constructor.

Comment: And even if the list *is* mutated, CPython (for example) uses a `BUILD_LIST` byte code to create the list rather than loading the name `'list'` and using `CALL_FUNCTION`. This means that even if you redefine the name `list`, `[...]` will still create a list, rather than calling your new function named `list`.